# move command dos not moving files in network share

Tags: batch-file

I have a really old batch file. It is supposed to move `test*.bak` files from one folder to another folder in the network share. Sometimes this code works sometimes it doesn't.

Here is the output I get I checked the result folder the files are moved but sometimes it leaves some files behind not sure why that is. The batch file is exiting with `1`. I cannot change the parameters sent to this application as it is coming from the mainframe.

Not sure if I am missing an if statement that checks if files exist in both folders?

Argument 1: `\\networkshare\folder1\test*.bak`
Argument 2: `\networkshare\result\`

Output:

```
*******************************************************
\\networkshare\folder2\filename.bak moved 
500+ files moved 
Move Unsuccessful!!
Return code 1 
A non-zero return code indicates file to be moved was not successful
*********************************************************
```

Here is my code:

```
REM move files 
REM \\networkshare\folder1\test*.bak to \\networkshare\folder2\

@echo OFF

echo PARAM 1:[%1]
echo PARAM 2:[%2]

set EXITCODE=0

move /Y %1 %2
set EXITCODE=%ERRORLEVEL%

if not "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
ECHO MOVE unsuccessful!!
set EXITCODE=%ERRORLEVEL%
goto EXIT_RST
)

ECHO MOVED SUCCESSFULLY 

:EXIT_RST
echo .
echo Return Code: %ERRORLEVEL%
echo A non-zero return code indicates file to be moved was not successful
echo .

exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Files have to be moved.

Comment: You are not using `EXITCODE` variable. Why are you using it? Also, you have two times the `exit` command in your batch file.

Comment: Also, you can try `if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (.......)`

Comment: If any of the paths have spaces in them, then they need to be quoted. Using quotes is a best practice regardless of needing them or not.

Comment: As above...`%~1` and `%~2` will remove the outer quotes when necessary.